# Solidity Contract Calls issue

Tags: aion

I created a dummy solidity contract (https://learn.aion.network/docs/deploy-a-smart-contract-using-web3) and deployed it.The issue occurs when I try to make a call using aion-web3.

```js
const contract = require('aion-web3-eth-contract');
contract.setProvider("https://aion.api.nodesmith.io/v1/mastery/jsonrpc?apiKey=*");
const Web3 = require('aion-web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://aion.api.nodesmith.io/v1/mastery/jsonrpc?apiKey=*"));

const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount("****");

let myContract = new contract([...], "0xa0e1166A455a0d75CFC2bfa32D7f76f0e1852c106b981Acf59EDE327CFD36811");
// console.log("C a",myContract.options.address);

myContract.methods.getCount().call({from: account.address}, function (error, result) {
    if (error){
        console.log("err=>", error)
    } else {
        console.log("res=>", result)
    }
});
```

I expect 0 because it the first call but its throwing the below error:

```
TypeError: myContract.methods.getCount is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the way you're trying to call the function isn't quite correct. Instead of creating a `myContract` object, try just putting the contract address into a transaction object, and then calling that:

```js
let transactionCall = {
    from: account.address, 
    to: "0xa0bf00624C2E81de745A826052D635f5c35515F0B55df6E4b1BAaCe785C124B9", 
    gas: 54321, 
        data: contractInst.methods.getCount().encodeABI()
};

web3.eth.call(transactionCall).then((res) => console.log(web3.utils.hexToNumber(res)));
```

Also, make sure that your account has coins in it. There's a faucet you can use here: https://faucets.blockxlabs.com/aion

Also, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Try use the following to create a contract instance:

```html
let myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(["compile contract abi info"])
```

And

```html
web3.eth.call({to:YourContractAddress, data:myContract.methods.getCount().encodeABI()}).then((res) => console.log(web3.utils.hexToNumber(res)));
```